# Does the new Spring MVC Test Framework released in Spring 3.2 test the web.xml configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing, web.xml, spring-test-mvc

I've read the docs ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework ) several times and I can't confirm if the `WebApplicationContext` context that gets injected when you use the `@WebApplicationContext` annotation is actually looking at the web.xml.

In other words, I want to test my web.xml configuration.  The filters and servlet path specifically.  But when I configure my test it ignores the web.xml.  (e.g. I try a `get` request on a URL like this `/myServletPath/foo` and it fails with a 404.)

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({
        "classpath*:WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml",
        "classpath*:WEB-INF/oms-servlet.xml",
        "classpath*:persistence-context.xml"
})
public class OrderSummaryControllerIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindOrderSummariesExpectsSuccess() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/oms/orders?user=1234&catalog=bcs"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <display-name>OMS REST Services</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>webappMetricsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.yammer.metrics.web.DefaultWebappMetricsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>webappMetricsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml, classpath*:persistence-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oms</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oms</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, Spring-mvc-test does not read the web.xml file, but you can configure the filters this way:

```
webAppContextSetup(this.wac).addFilter(new DefaultWebappMetricsFilter(), "/*").build()
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's helpful.  I'm still not sure why the creation of the mock needs the location of the web application root if it's not reading the web.xml.  See my comment on Ralph's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14026570/411229.

Comment: because it does use other resources from the web application root - for eg. if you had placed your Spring web application configuration in say WEB-INF/spring/appcontext.xml, although not in the classpath it would still be able to access and load it in the test.

Comment: that makes sense.  The documentation isn't very clear on that point.  Thanks for clearing it up.